# Setting a timeout for a session after a user has logged in

Tags: php, session, cookies

I've got a login page that needs to close if a user has been inactive for a certain amount of time.  I figured that setting the session variables to cookies would be the best way to do this(If there's a better way or if my way is wrong, please tell me).  The problem is that the session is being destroyed and cookies are being unset before the script has run.  Should I move the if statement to the bottom of the page?  Should I even need the if statement?  Am I even doing this right?  Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    require("../includes/header.php");
    $expire = time() + 90;
    setcookie("User", $_SESSION["user"], $expire);
    setcookie("Image", $_SESSION["image"], $expire);
    setcookie("Program", $_SESSION["program"], $expire);
    setcookie("Email", $_SESSION["email"], $expire);
    setcookie("Role", $_SESSION["role"], $expire);
    if($expire){
        unset($_COOKIE["User"]);
        unset($_COOKIE["Image"]);
        unset($_COOKIE["Program"]);
        unset($_COOKIE["Email"]);
        unset($_COOKIE["Role"]);
        session_destroy();
        echo "Session has expired.";
    }
?> 
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <header>
            <div id="logo" class="logo_bg"></div>
            <div id="fsi_logo" class="logo_bg"></div>
        </header>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="instructor">
                <?php
                    echo "<img id=instructor_image src=" .$_COOKIE["Image"] .">";
                    echo "<h1>" .$_COOKIE["User"] ."</h1>";
                    echo "<span><p>" .$_COOKIE["Program"] ."</p> - <h2>" .$_COOKIE["Role"] ."</h2></span>";
                    echo "<a href=mailto:" .$_COOKIE["Email"] .">" .$_COOKIE["Email"] ."</a>";
                ?>
            </div>
<?php require("../includes/footer.html"); ?>
```

Comment: I had to do something similar, and I know this does not answer your question, but if you don't mind JS or some Jquery, there is a plugin called idle timeout that works quite nicely and is easy to install.

Comment: I'm actually using jQuery to do front end work functionality.  I will check out the plugin, I really don't want to use any more plugins on the front end though.  If it comes down to it, though, I'll probably use it.  Thanks for that reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example if($expire) is always true. You don't have to move it to the bottom of the page if you store the expire time in a session. Something like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["expire"])) {
    $_SESSION["expire"] = time() + 90; // This would add 90 seconds though...

    // More set logic
} elseif($_SESSION["expire"] < time()) {
    // Unset logic
} else {
    // Refresh timer
}
```

Comment: So how would I set the time to be 90 seconds for instance?  Would it be time(90)?

Comment: What you did was correct, you've added 90 seconds to current time().